# Load Shortcode Wordpress Until Page Load Finish

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem loading my shortcode wordpress but it's working on php, the problem is I have to take 4-5 seconds to generate shortcode because the shortcode has to proccess my internal script, so I think I have to load the shortcode after the page load finishes, maybe using ajax can resolve but I'm not good at using ajax language.

Here my script :

```
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_stok_widget', 'stok_widget' );
function stok_widget() {
    global $product;
    $result = "Not found.";

    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_product()) {
        // do proccess
    }

    return $result ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (AJAX) and PHP are two different languages. The only way to work using shortcodes in WordPress is with PHP.

A solution would be to insert a div or some other element you need using the shortcode, and assign it a unique ID or classname. Then, using JavaScript, you could check if the element persists on the page, and if so, do an AJAX call which does the process you would like to execute.

Another option would be to figure out why it takes so long before the shortcode gets generated. Maybe there is a possibility to cache the result and serve it instantly?

Comment: I using cache wp-rocket and work perfectly but in single product page i have to get data from another API link so that's why I need to load the shortcodes until page load finish. anyway i very bad for javascript languange so i don't know how implement to ajax.

Comment: Ah I see why it would take so long. I think a shortcode isn't what you're looking for, unless you can cache (and maybe even prefetch) the result of the API request.